# How to get a list of the most recent videos uploaded to multiple YouTube channels?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get a list of the most recent videos uploaded to multiple YouTube channels in the order that they were uploaded. Sort of like how the subscription box on YouTube shows all of the recent videos uploaded by multiple people (that you are subscribed to).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
part=snippet&channelId=UC4XmzE3vYbp7h4B8dxcoN_A&maxResults=20&order=date
&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

That search will return a list of the most recent videos uploaded from a single channel. However, I'm trying to display a group of people within the same list.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
part=snippet
&channelId={UCXA7dMwWUS8n00Xq-Qvj38A,UC4XmzE3vYbp7h4B8dxcoN_A}
&maxResults=20&order=date&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I've tried adding an additional YouTube `channelId` (separated by a comma) with the first one, and that seems to break the search and shows "random" videos (none from either `channelId` listed).

If anyone knows how to accomplish this with one API query, I'd be very happy.

---

To be more clear, as I mentioned in a comment below, this is what I'm looking to do:

> I'm not trying to get a specific users "subscriptions", but instead
>   I'm trying to                    combine multiple channels recent
>   uploads (videos) into one list. This way I can display my     "teams"
>   videos in chronological order on my website in the order that they are
>   uploaded.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your question? I'm trying to do the same thing without making hundreds of individual API calls for every user. Maybe you could answer your own question with how you did it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [activities->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) call for this with home=true.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&home=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Then you can filter only [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#snippet.type)=upload responses.

[More info here.](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/09/what-to-watch-our-apis-can-help.html)

But if you are looking for specific channels, there is no multichannel search, you can get uploads playlists from each channel and merge it yourself.

For each, do a channels->list request with channelId to get uploadsPlaylist then do a playlistItems->list with that playlistId to get items, you can stop adding items to your own list once [publishedAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.publishedAt) of that video is out of your boundary.

Comment: As far as I know, that doesn't allow you to get the activity from multiple channels?

Comment: Just as your home page, you will get activities of all the relevant channels.

Comment: I'm not trying to get a specific users "subscriptions", but instead I'm trying to combine multiple channels recent uploads (videos) into one list. This way I can display my "teams" videos in chronological order on my website in the order that they are uploaded.

Comment: There is no multichannel search, you can get uploads playlists from each channel and merge it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a request for each channel, there is no multichannel search API.

Not sure if Google intends to implement one, but hopefully they do.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a source?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId), listing currently supports requests only per one channel, for example as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&order=date&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

There is currently no functionality for multichannel search (see reference above), but since the return format is well-defined you can simply make multiple calls, one for each of your desired channels and then merge the results, sorting by date.